# Remove GIT from OSX Catalina

Tags: git

Good Day

I've used the following:sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/git, it ask's for the password which I enter and it returns "Operation not permitted".

I'm the only user.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Based on the directory, it seems like you're trying to uninstall the git that was bundled with the OS; removing software that comes with the system is generally not a good idea. Can I ask why you're trying to remove git?

Comment: Despite the fact that `git` is generally a programming tool, this is a question unrelated to programming (you could just as easily replace `git` with any other program and the question still makes sense). I'd suggest asking over on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ since it's likely to be Apple-specific.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies. I believe I found the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248220/how-to-remove-default-git-or-update-it)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about programming but a question about OS X system administration. Should be migrated to https://apple.stackexchange.com/